# How do I prove that the sum of $x_1 + x_2$ and $x_1 \cdot x_2$ is rational?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, rational-numbers

Given an equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, with $a, b$ and $c$ being whole numbers, and this equation having two solutions. The solutions of such an equation are sometimes rational, but mostly not. How do you prove that the sum of the solutions $x_1 + x_2$ and the product $x_1 \cdot x_2$ are always rational?

Comment: Use the quadratic formula to find $x_1$ and $x_2$, and then simply add and multiply them.

Comment: I don't want to prove this for certain values of x1 and x2, but for the general form. So proving that the sum of the solutions x1 + x2 and the product x1 * x2 are always rational, regardless of the values of x1 and x2.

Comment: And you can do that by following the directions that I gave in my previous comment. No specific numbers are involved. For example, what is $$\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}+\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\;?$$

Comment: It's even easier - if you expand $a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ you will get the original equation, and so we see that the sum is $-b/a$ and product is $c/a$ by comparing terms.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That'd be -2b / 2a = -(b/a), but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: You know that $a$ and $b$ are integers; what does that tell you about $-\frac{b}a$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Aha, -b/a is a rational number! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Now you’ve got it! You’re welcome.

Comment: It seems that you can lead a horse to water, but not make it realize the water is right in front of it.

Comment: See Vieta's formulas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: They are rational if $a,b,c$ are. I find out your question to be a bit confusing as you said $a,b,c$ are whole numbers.

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn It's because the OP questioned his answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, the idea here is to simply use the formula
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},$$
from which it follows that
$$x_1+x_2=-\frac ba,\quad x_1x_2=\frac ca.$$
These are called [*Vieta's formulas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Vieta's%20formulas%20are,are%20used%20specifically%20in%20algebra.) and can be generalised to polynomials of arbitrary degree.